# Russian characters are not getting decoded when accessing url directly

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

The nuxt-link works fine, but when I reload, it can't find the route.
The translated routes are informed like this:

`nuxtI18n: { paths: { en: "/for-sale/", es: "/en-venta/", ru: "/для-продажи/", } }`

I have observed that if I go directly to the encoded path, it will work, but if I use the russian characters it won't.
So if I go to [http://localhost:3000/ru/для-продажи](http://localhost:3000/ru/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8) won't work, but going to http://localhost:3000/ru/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8 will.

How can I make it so it will encode russian characters when looking for route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem disappeared by adding

```
// nuxt.config.js

['nuxt-i18n', {
  encodePaths: false
}]
```